# Cron Expression in Spring

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have one requirement to send mails on weekly basis at some point based on some database check and its working perfectly fine with below config.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>              
            <ref bean="emailWeeklyNotification"/>
        </list>
    </property> 
    <property name="triggers">
        <list> 
            <ref bean="emailWeeklyTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="emailWeeklyTrigger"   class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean"> 
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="emailWeeklyNotification" />  
    <property name="cronExpression" value="${email.weekly.sched}" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="emailWeeklyNotification" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">     
    <property name="targetObject" ref="emailService" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="myMthod" />     
</bean>
```

**${email.weekly.sched}** for this value is coming from DB like **"0 0 6 ? * MON"**

**emailService** is a my Class which is having this method with some other placeholders.

So my question is, what to write in this expression which will break Spring's code so my scheduler method should not be called becuse there is nothing in DB and still mails are going.

Though this going to be a temp fix becuase we have new code, which is checking the size of collection before sending mails, but not in PROD.

I tried writing like **"0 -1 17 ? * THU"** or **"0 56 17 ? * FUN"** but its failing in deployment itself.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: In short: you ask for a  (spring) cron expression that never triggers, right?

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.util.StringUtils.CronSequenceGenerator` seams to have no way to have a pattern that stop triggering.

Comment: You mean, we cant do that?